# Run a script with ng server Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api, typescript

I need to run a script every time I use the `ng serve` command, I'm preparing I server to receive POST from an API. My question is if when I run `firebase deploy` from the `/dist` folder, it will start this server so I get POST from an API in my application.

Below is the file I need to run via `localhost` with command `ng serve` within **Firebase Hosting** when running `firebase deploy` command.

In my `angular.json` file I tried as follows:

```
                    "assets": [
                        "src/favicon.ico",
                        "src/assets",
                        "src/server-api/server.js"
                    ],
```

At the moment I'm only able to execute by setting a script through `package.json`.

```
  "scripts": {
    "app-main": "ng build && node ./server-api/server.js",
}
```

**server.js:**

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

**api.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "myapikey",
    authDomain: "myapp-30d6b.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "myapp-30d6b",
});

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
var db = firebase.firestore();

router.post('/notifications', (req, res) => {
    res.status(201).json({
        notification: req.body
    });

    db.collection("notifications").add(req.body)
        .then(function (docRef) {
            console.log("Success: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error", error);
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "app-main": "ng build && node server.js",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "start-hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr -sm=false",
    "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
    "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "8.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "12.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "4.0.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.9.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.24.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.6",
    "creditcard.js": "2.1.3",
    "d3": "5.2.0",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "firebase": "5.0.3",
    "firebase-admin": "5.12.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "5.3.1",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.10",
    "ngx-mask": "2.7.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.6.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "prismjs": "1.14.0",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.11.1"
  }
}
```

**The solution I'm looking for:**

I need it to work when I run `ng serve` or else when my application is hosted on Firebase Hosting through the `firebase deploy` command.

That way I can receive POST in my Angular application.

Comment: Do you have an order of running, like running the script before the ng server ?

Comment: I need to run this script every time I run `ng serve` and ensure that when my application is hosted on **Firebase Hosting** it will be running to **receive POST** and send to my database.

Comment: can you post your package.json ? I wanna see the script you use to run your ng serve

Comment: If you're deploying the dist directory, surely there is no need to run `ng serve`?

Comment: I do not need to run `ng serve`, but I wanted to run when my application in Angular is running, because I want to make sure everything is working inside Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Adicionado package.json

Answer (score 4):

you can use the pre/post hooks for npm explained here:

http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html#hooks-pre-and-post

try adding these 2 scripts to your package.json and then run `npm run server:dev`

`"preserver:dev": "node ./server-api/server.js",`
`"server:dev": "ng serve --configuration=dev",`

Comment: Will this only work when I run the command or when my application is hosted on Firebase Hosting?

Comment: I'm really not sure about Firebase

Comment: I need it to work when my application runs. This way I believe it will only be executed through the command. The script should run whenever my application in Angular is running.

Comment: I think so yeah, give it a shot and see how it goes

Comment: The purpose of this is to prepare my application to receive POST from an API, get the JSON received and save it to my bank.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this. Firebase hosting is for static hosting. It doesn't run `ng serve` when you `firebase deploy`, it just serves the static files...

Comment: Can I run what's inside server.js in my main.ts? Because ng build --prod creates the main.js within / dist which is what Firebase Hosting performs.

Comment: Yes, but what's in the dist directory is never executed on the Firebase server-- it's executed in the clients browser. It's unlikely that you would be able to bind to one of their ports even if you managed to get the script to run on their machine

Comment: locally you can do that by running 2 servers, but as @user184994 you can't run the API one (port 3000) in firebase.